# Google Chrome Tab-Enter key malfunction

Tags: google-chrome

When I use 'Tab' Key in Google Chrome, instead of just jumping to the next filed, it jumps and also adds a tab character to the next field. Also, the 'Enter' key doesnt actually go to a new line. I have uninstalled and reinstalled Google chrome multiple times but didnt help. This doesnt happen in other browsers such as Firefox, IE etc. Neither does happen in other computer. I cant figure out what setting could have changed. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You may have a plugin that has gone-rogue, and is creating this functionality.